# how change back image and select image?

Tags: iphone

i make app. and i don`t change backimage

i want this picture:

[image]

i tried two way.

one is ( UISegmentedControl name is 'seg')

```
seg = [[UIsegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:nil];
[seg insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ttt.png"] atIndex:0 animated:FALSE];
[seg insertSegmentWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ttt_1.png"] atIndex:1 animated:FALSE];
```

other way is ..

```
[seg setImage:.........];
```

i hope change like that picture..

plz help me...

Answer (score 0):

Use this method.....

```
[segmentedcontrol setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"down_arrow.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:1];
```